# Find complex numbers (coefficients) from known roots

Tags: complex-numbers

I am stuck on this:
Find the complex numbers (the coefficients) c0, c1 og c2 so the polynomial equation will be
$P (z) = z^3 + c_2z^2 + c_1z + c_0$

and have the roots $z = i$, $z = 1 + 5i $, z = −2

I've come so far:
$(z-i)(z+2)(z-(1+5i))$
$=z^3-3z^2-6z^2+13zi-3z+10$

But dont know how to continue. And by the way, with one of the three roots does have a conjugate, doesnt seem like they do, since all three roots are different from each other...

Comment: You've solved the question, what are you trying to ask?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Substitute $z$  in $P(z)$ with the known roots and set equal to zero  for each known root: $P(z_{root})=0$ , then you will get 3 equations with 3 unknowns... I suppose you can take it from there!

Comment: That is a ludicrous way of doing it! Just expand as he did in the question

Answer (score 0):

Notice, Substituting, in turn, all three roots $z=i$, $z=1+5i$ & $z=-2$ in the given equation $P(z)=z^3+c_2z^2+c_1z+c_0$, one gets three linear equations as follows $$c_2-ic_1-c_0=-i\tag 1$$
$$\color{}{2(12-5i)c_2-(1+5i)c_1-c_0=-2(37+55i)}\tag 2$$
$$4c_2-2c_1+c_0=8\tag 3$$ adding (1) & (3), one gets $$5c_2-(2+i)c_1=8-i\tag 4$$
adding (2) & (3), one gets $$2(14-5i)c_2-(3+5i)c_1=-2(33+55i)\tag 5$$
I hope you can solve (4) & (5), one gets 
$$\color{red}{c_1=-(7+11i), \ \ c_2=1-\frac{26}{5}i}$$
then substituting values of $c_1$  & $c_2$ in (1), one gets $$\color{red}{c_0=-10+\frac{14}{5}i}$$

Comment: How do I solve from (4)& (5)? I seem to end up with both c1 and c2 in the equation on both sides and can't go on...

Comment: You can simply substitute the value of $c_1=\frac{(8-i)+c_1(2+i)}{5}$ from (4) into (5) & solve for $c_1$, you will get $c_1=-(7+11i)$. Then substitute this value of $c_1$ into (4) you will get $c_2=1-\frac{26}{5}i$